# how to perform join using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, projection

So i have one simple hibernate related question

First table:

```
Aggregated_order
  aggregated_order_id
  phone_order_id
```

Second table:

```
Returns
  phone_order_id
```

So I need to select all the aggregated_order_id from the first table, whose corresponding phone_order_id is in the second table (returns).

ie. I need to return all aggregated orders, which have phone returns.

How do i do this using hibernate??
Do i use projections?
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins. Hibernate queries use entities, not tables.

Comment: Do you have your DAO's and hibernate xml documents created?

Comment: yes! now i need to use Criteria to select the mentioned field